# Cannot get AG Grid data to refresh on Button Click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-query

I've recently started reworking a project and am learning react and, more recently, have been attempting to make use of a combination of React Query and AG Grid to display a set of data.

My data is derived from a React Query connecting to an API.

This seems like it should be simple... after I've made a visual change on one of the react fields, I want to discard it. So I have a cancel button that calls a function... to my understanding, this should simply call setDataRows and pass it the data value from my useQuery call.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { getMemberList } from "../functions/dataConnections";
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

function App( ) {    
    const { data, status } = useQuery('members', getMemberList);
    const gridRef = useRef();
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

    const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
         {
            field: 'FirstName',         
            editable: true,         
            headerName: 'First Name*',         
            cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor'
        },     
        {
            field: 'LastName',         
            editable: true,         
            headerName: 'Last Name*',         
            cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor'
        }
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setRowData(data)
    }, [data]);

    const cancelChangesClicked = useCallback( () => {
        setRowData(data);            
    }, [data]);

    if (status === 'loading') {
        return <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    if(status === 'error'){

        return <p>Error!</p>
    }

    return (

        <div className='ag-theme-alpine'  style={{height: 700, width:'100%'}}>
            <button onClick={cancelChangesClicked}>Cancel Changes</button>
            <AgGridReact
                ref={gridRef}
                rowData={rowData} 
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
                enableCellChangeFlash={true}
                pagination={true} 
                paginationAutoPageSize={true} />
        </div>
    )        
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after much digging, I found my answer... though it is not clearly explained elsewhere.

When you change a value on a field in AG Grid, it alters the undprogrammatically.

This means that all their methods for refreshing the data only apply if the values displayed by the fields were altered programmatically.

In order to actually refresh the grid and clear all changes... or more accurately, to  set the display values back to what they should be, you have to put a refresh() command before you set the datarow.

This only seems to be necessary if your initial data is pulled in from an Api and not (like most tutorials seem to be set up) from a explicitly written data set within the code itself.